# Forcing rails to autoload class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

I have several small classes that are in a single file in /app/models, similar to:

```
# /app/models/little_class.rb
class LittleClass; ...do stuff; end;
class AnotherLittleClass; ...do stuff; end;
```

Rails only seems geared to autoload classes in files reflecting the class name.  So referencing AnotherLittleClass outside of the file raises "unitialized constant" errors as below until LittleClass is referenced:

```
irb(main):001:0> AnotherLittleClass 
NameError: uninitialized constant AnotherLittleClass
irb(main):02:0> LittleClass
=> LittleClass
irb(main):03:0> AnotherLittleClass
=> LittleClass2
```

It would be a pain and messy to split them into individual files.  Is there a way to autoload these classes, so referencing AnotherLittleClass without LittleClass doesnt raise an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this trick:

```
1.9.2p312 :001 > AnotherLittleClass.new
# => NameError: uninitialized constant AnotherLittleClass
1.9.2p312 :002 > autoload :AnotherLittleClass, File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/app/models/little_class.rb"
# => nil 
1.9.2p312 :003 > AnotherLittleClass.new
# => #<AnotherLittleClass:0xa687d24>
```

Comment: Hmmm, that gets it.  Bummer that I have to manually specify all the classes though.  Thanks @WarHog

Comment: However this trick will break reloading of the classes by Rails if you care about that. So if you will make any changes to these classes, you will have to restart the app.

Answer (score 4):

You could put them into a module and use them within this namespace `SomeLittleClasses::LittleClass.do_something`

```
# /app/models/some_little_classes.rb
module SomeLittleClasses

  class LittleClass
    def self.do_something
      "Hello World!"
    end
  end

  class AnotherLittleClass
    def self.do_something
      "Hello World!"
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

These are your choices, as I see it:

1. split your file up into one file per class, put them in a dir named according to the rails convention (`SomeClass` => `some_class.rb`) and in a startup file  (say, create a file in `config/initializers`), call:

   ```
   autoload_paths Rails.application.config.root + "/path/to/lib"
   ```
2. add something like this to a startup file:

   ```
   %W[
       Class1 Class2
       Class3 Class4 Class4
   ].map(&:to_sym).each dp |klass|
       autoload klass,Rails.application.config.root + "/path/to/lib/file"
   end
   ```

   This of course will have to be updated each time a new class is added to the file.
3. Move all of the classes into a module/class namespace and call `autoload` to add it as above
4. just load the whole file up-front in a startup file with `require`.  Ask yourself: does the extra effort warrant delaying the load of this file?

Answer (score 0):

The following file `app/models/statistic.rb` is given :

```
class Statistic
  # some model code here
end

class UsersStatistic < Statistic; end
class CommentsStatistic < Statistic; end
class ConnectionsStatistic < Statistic; end
```

Create a file `config/initializers/autoload_classes.rb` and add the following code:

```
# Autoloading subclasses that are in the same file


# This is the normal way to load single classes
#
# autoload :UsersStatistic, 'statistic'
# autoload :CommentsStatistic, 'statistic'
# autoload :ConnectionsStatistic, 'statistic'


# This is the most dynamic way for production and development environment.
Statistic.subclasses.each do |klass|
  autoload klass.to_s.to_sym, 'statistic'
end



# This does the same but loads all subclasses automatically. 
# Useful only in production environment because every file-change 
# needs a restart of the rails server.
# 
# Statistic.subclasses
```